# jQuery plugins, need a crossfade plugin

Tags: jquery, hibernate, plugins

Been looking for a plugin that will allow both cross fading AND the image to be clickable so that the user can be sent to a new url [not advance the slider!] or download a file...

anyone have any suggestions?

-sean

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions?  I have tried multiple javascript solutions but the performance is terrible in IE8 and below so ended up using a Flash solution (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be CPU intensive but allows for clickable images and crossfading. [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest - http://bxslider.com/

I've used it on a few websites, simpel and easy to setup, you can add URL's into the elements too, which can take the user off to a new URL.

Any questions, or help give me a shout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one
http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/

It allows linking as well as fading and is very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

SlidesJS does both of those things. bxSlider does not have cross fading.